# Loading image is showing all server side request as well as client side request in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

In our project, we have all type of button and links like link button, image button, normal button and HTML buttons and i want to show loading image when page is going to load but some time while saving page if any validation error occurs then loading image is showing and if HTML anchor tag i am clicking then it also showing me loading message. I am working in big project so i want to bind all event at once on master page ASP.NET.

Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #dvLoading {
    background: url(/images/activity.gif) no-repeat center center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    }
</style>

<div id="dvLoading" style="display:none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        //$('#dvLoading').toggle('slow');
        $('#dvLoading').slideDown();
    });
    $("input:image").click(function(event){ 
        //$('#dvLoading').toggle('slow');
        $('#dvLoading').slideDown();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried registering your script on Form Submit?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(" if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == 'function' && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {\n");
sb.Append("     return false; \n");
sb.Append(" } \n");
sb.Append(" $('#dvLoading').slideDown(); \n");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "displayLoadingPanelOnFormSumbit", sb.ToString());
```